# NPE when loading custom SecurityConfig for Keycloak in WebMvcTest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak, mockmvc

In the webapp itself everything runs without any problem. The auth works as expected. However, since I have Spring Security on my classpath, all my controller tests are now failing because the default Spring Security configuration is being loaded. Obviously, I want my SecurityConfig to be loaded, because I for example configured that csrf is diabled and that by default every endpoint can be accessed without authentication. 
But when I want to load my SecurityConfig, I get a NPE when running my test.

I am using the Keycloak adapters in a Spring Boot application via `org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-boot-starter` and `org.keycloak.bom:keycloak-adapter-bom:9.0.2`. My Spring Boot version is `2.2.6.RELEASE`.

**Stacktrace when running the test**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.internalBuild(KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.java:57)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.build(KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.java:202)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver.resolve(KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver.java:39)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.config.KeycloakSpringConfigResolverWrapper.resolve(KeycloakSpringConfigResolverWrapper.java:40)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.AdapterDeploymentContext.resolveDeployment(AdapterDeploymentContext.java:89)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:183)
    at net.my.domain.exampledomain.controller.ExampleControllerTest.givenExampleRouteURIWithAcceptApplicationXml_whenMockMVC_thenVerifyResponse(ExampleControllerTest.java:43)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
```

**SecurityConfig**

```
@KeycloakConfiguration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider =
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
    keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
    auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
  }

  @Bean
  public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
    return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
  }

  @Bean
  @Override
  protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
    return new NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy();
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
  }
}
```

**ExampleControllerTest**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(ExampleController.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ExampleController.class, SecurityConfig.class})
public class ExampleControllerTest {

  @Autowired private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Test
  public void givenExampleRouteURIWithAcceptApplicationXml_whenMockMVC_thenVerifyResponse()
          throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc
            .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/exampleroute").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
  }
}
```

Comment: What if you replace WebMvcTest with SpringBootTest and remove ContextConfiguration. Does it work then? Btw. you can remove RunWith

Comment: I now have the following annotations on **ExampleControllerTest**: `@SpringBootTest(classes = WebApplication.class)
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase
@AutoConfigureMockMvc`. I get the exact same stacktrace.

Comment: I don't know why, but this seemed to break when moving from 9.0.0 to 9.0.2 (or newer) for me.  I've asked this same question on their forum: https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/breaking-change-in-9-0-1-9-0-2/3656

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something that broke with 9.0.1 (though I guess you'd only see it starting from 9.0.2, since 9.0.1 is [missing](https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/keycloak-9-0-1-missing-from-central/3653) from both the JBoss repo and Maven Central repo).  This will be fixed in 11.0 ([KEYCLOAK-14520](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-14520)).  In the mean time, you can workaround by

1. Delete your `KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver` bean that was required through 9.0.0
2. Add the workaround mentioned in the Jira

```java
@Configuration
public class SpringBootKeycloakConfigResolver implements KeycloakConfigResolver {
    private KeycloakDeployment keycloakDeployment;
    private AdapterConfig adapterConfig;

    @Autowired
    public SpringBootKeycloakConfigResolver(AdapterConfig adapterConfig) {
        this.adapterConfig = adapterConfig;
    }

    @Override
    public KeycloakDeployment resolve(OIDCHttpFacade.Request request) {
        if (keycloakDeployment != null) {
            return keycloakDeployment;
        }
        keycloakDeployment = KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.build(adapterConfig);
        return keycloakDeployment;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. That seems to be the same bug, that I am experiencing. However, I didn't manage to apply the workaround without a hassle. But since version 11 is close, I am just going to wait for that release.

Comment: Where'd you see that 11 was close? I hadn't found any particular timeframe mentioned.

Comment: It got mentioned in a comment in a related ticket. He didn't say, what "close" actually means, though. Here is the link to the comment: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-14020?focusedCommentId=14184491&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14184491